# How do I automatically create a word doc from an incoming email and have it sit in my drop box account?

Tags: email, ms-word

I have a MAC and I want to automate it so that if I send an email to one of my accounts, that email is immediately copied on to a word document that sits in my drop box account. Any ideas or suggestions are very much appreciated,

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should start learning [AppleScript](http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/applescript/the-ultimate-beginners-guide-to-applescript/).
Then get familiar with [Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2488).
[Automator Actions for Mail.app](http://www.hawkwings.net/2006/05/27/automator-actions-for-mailapp/) to export to a text file in a directory.
[Folder Actions](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/01/30/folder-actions-for-os-x-explained-with-real-world-examples/) to convert that text file into a Word document and move it into your DropBox folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I checked out the links you mentioned and am trying to learn apple script. I have never worked with any kind of code before and am having some difficulty with this. Is there any chance you could put me on the right track for this task?